# How can I create mock tags to test with NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

How can do i create ndef messages in byte form? I've read somewhere it need to have a special start/end byte, is it true?

Comment: Were you trying to create a mock tag, or just ndef message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need the message in bytes, but once you created a NdefMessage you can call the toByteArray() method to return a byte array. Same is true for NdefRecord.

Comment: Does this create a mock tag?

Answer (score 1):

I have released an [NFC Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) for composing NDEF messages of various sorts, you might find it useful. It will produce binary NDEF files.

Doing the same programmatically, have a look at [NFC Tools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools) tools or (another project of mine) [NDEF Tools for Android](https://github.com/skjolber/ndef-tools-for-android).

If you're not able to mock the Tags directly (i.e. using mockito), you can use a (another project of mine) [wrapper](https://github.com/skjolber/android-nfc-wrapper) and either mock the wrapper object directly or manipulate the service it connects to.

Comment: Get Eclipse, install the plugin, create a file with an .ndef extension.